# How to retrieve data within an a href tag

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, web-crawler, href

Hey all i've stumbled across some difficulties whilst web crawling. I am trying to obtain the 70 in this chunk of code embedded in the middle of some html, my question is how would i go about doing so.I've tried various methods but none seem to work. I'm using the BeautifulSoup module and writing in Python 3.The link to the website i'm scraping is conveniently the link in the href if anyone needs it.Thank you in advance.

```
<a href="http://www.accuweather.com/en/gb/london/ec4a-2/weather- forecast/328328">London, United Kingdom<span class="temp">70&deg;</span><span  class="icon i-33-s"></span></a>

from bs4 import*
import requests
data = requests.get("http://www.accuweather.com/en/gb/london/ec4a-2/weather-   forecast/328328")
soup = BeautifulSoup(data.text,"html.parser")
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming using `BeautifulSoup` is not a strict requirement, you could do this with the `html.parser` module. The below is custom designed for the use-case you have mentioned. 
It fetches both the data fields and then filters out the number.

```
from html.parser import HTMLParser

class MyHTMLParser(HTMLParser):
    def handle_data(self, data):
        if data.isdigit():
            print(data)

parser = MyHTMLParser()

parser.feed('<a href="http://www.accuweather.com/en/gb/london/ec4a-2/weather- forecast/328328">London, United Kingdom<span class="temp">70&deg;</span><span  class="icon i-33-s"></span></a>')
```

this will output `70`

Could also be done using regex.

Comment: It could also be done like this but im trying to web scrape a weather website where the 70 is the weather and the a tag i sent is in the middle of some html

Answer (score 0):

This will get you any spans containing a temperature

```
temps = soup.find_all('span',{'class':'temp'})
```

Then loop over it

```
for span in temps:
    temp = span.decode_contents() 
    # temp looks like "70&deg" or "70\xb0" so parse it
    print int(temp[:-1])
```

The hard work is probably converting from unicode to ASCII if you are in python2.

But the accu-weather page doesn't have a span with class temp:

```
In [12]: soup.select('[class~=temp]')
Out[12]: 
[<strong class="temp">19<span>\xb0</span></strong>,
 <strong class="temp">14<span>\xb0</span></strong>,
 <strong class="temp">24<span>\xb0</span></strong>,
 <strong class="temp">23<span>\xb0</span></strong>,
 <h2 class="temp">19\xb0</h2>,
 <h2 class="temp">19\xb0</h2>,
 <h2 class="temp">17\xb0</h2>,
 <h2 class="temp">19\xb0</h2>,
 <h2 class="temp">19\xb0</h2>,
 <h2 class="temp">19\xb0</h2>,
 <h2 class="temp">20\xb0</h2>,
 <h2 class="temp">19\xb0</h2>,
 <h2 class="temp">17\xb0</h2>,
 <h2 class="temp">19\xb0</h2>,
 <h2 class="temp">19\xb0</h2>]
```

So it's harder to give you an answer

Comment: At first it looked like it was going to work but it didnt

Comment: Of course, that page at accu-weather doesn't use a span with class temp any more. It's using 'h2' and 'strong' instead

Comment: It does have a span with a  temp class if you get the correct source, you can see this if you go to the page in your browser.

Comment: It does have a class called temp

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a user-agent to get the correct source, then select using the tag/class names you want:

```
from bs4 import *
import requests
headers = {"user-agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/52.0.2743.82 Safari/537.36"}
data = requests.get("http://www.accuweather.com/en/gb/london/ec4a-2/weather-forecast/328328", headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(data.content)
print(soup.select_one("span.local-temp").text)
print([span.text for span in soup.select("span.temp")])
```

If we run the code, you see we get all we need:

```
In [17]: headers = {
   ....:     "user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/52.0.2743.82 Safari/537.36"}

In [18]: data = requests.get("http://www.accuweather.com/en/gb/london/ec4a-2/weather-forecast/328328", headers=headers)

In [19]: soup = BeautifulSoup(data.content, "html.parser")

In [20]: print(soup.find("span", "local-temp").text)
18°C

In [21]: print("\n".join([span.text for span in soup.select("span.temp")]))
18°
31°
30°
25°
```

Comment: No worries, always good to  check the source returned from the request and in the actual source in the browser when you right click and choose view source.

Comment: I have a couple questions though,what is the user agent and why do you need it.Also what do these lines of code do , soup.select_one("span.local-temp").text and print([span.text for span in soup.select("span.temp")])

Comment: @goimpress, depending on your user-agent you can be served different content https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_agent, `span.local-temp` and `span.temp` are css selectors, you could use `find("local-temp")` and `find_all("span",{"class":"temp"})`, I just prefer using selectors, https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors

Answer (score -1):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
import requests
soup = BeautifulSoup(text,"html.parser")
for link in soup.find("a")
   temp = link.find("span",{"class" : "temp"})
   print(re.findall(r"[0-9]{1,2}",temp.text))
```

I hope this helps you

Comment: Thanks for your comment! but that prints out all the links and im trying to obtain the "70" in that a tag